# what is the name of the second parameter for `CpiContext`

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, program

For example, when calling the instruction to mint_to my wallet,

I initialize the cpi_context

```
    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            MintTo {
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.associated_token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
            },
        );
```

Is there a name for the second argument `MintTo`?

Answer (score 4):

Once in awhile, you have to pull out the oldie-but-goodie: use the source, Luke!

If we look at the definition of `CpiContext::new` at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/3c6fc2ba2d06a799b53b27a282e5c811b978cdf5/lang/src/context.rs#L179, we'll see that it's just called `accounts`, but it's a generic type `T`.

The generic type `T` is defined as anything implementing `ToAccountMetas` and `ToAccountInfos`, meaning any struct that you can iterate over to get account metas for instruction creation: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/3c6fc2ba2d06a799b53b27a282e5c811b978cdf5/lang/src/context.rs#L167

And the trait at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/3c6fc2ba2d06a799b53b27a282e5c811b978cdf5/lang/src/lib.rs#L117

Answer (score 1):

It's just a struct with the arguments for the cpi context, try writing it as:

```
    pub fn mint_token_to_user(&self, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
            mint: self.some_mint.to_account_info(),
            to: self.user_acc.to_account_info(),
            authority: self.some_auth.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext {
            program: self.token_program.to_account_info(),
            accounts: cpi_accounts,
            remaining_accounts: Vec::new(),
            signer_seeds: &[some_seeds_if_needed],
        };
        token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, amount)
    }
```

Now it's more obvious that mint_to is a pub function of token, which itself calls `solana_program::program::invoke_signed` with `to`, `mint`, and `authority` as accountInfo from your args in the MintTo Context struct.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, the second argument of `CpiContext::new` is an instance of the `MintTo` struct. It doesn't have a specific "name" in the context of the `CpiContext` constructor, but it's simply an instance of a struct that you are passing as an argument to the constructor.

Here's a breakdown of the `CpiContext::new` call:

```
let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
    ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
    MintTo {
        mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.associated_token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
    },
);
```

- The first argument is the token program's account info.
- The second argument is an instance of the `MintTo` struct, which represents the instruction and its associated data that you want to execute.

In this case, you are initializing `cpi_context` with the `MintTo` struct, which contains the necessary account information and data for the `mint_to` instruction. So, there isn't a specific name for this argument in the `CpiContext` constructor, but it's a struct that you are passing to it.